# Bash scripting checking content of a variable containing a directory path

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a simple bash script on Ubuntu 12.10 which stores the result of the pwd command in a variable and then checks the value of that variable in an if command to see if it matches a particular string. But I keep getting an error because it treats the content of that variable as a directory itself and keeps giving the error "No such file or directory"

The program is as below:

```
myvar=$(pwd)
if [$myvar -eq /home/vicky] #fails this check as variable myvar contains /home/vicky
then
    echo correct
else
    echo incorrect
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you aware that saying `$(pwd)` or `$PWD` would return you the directory from where you are executing the script and **not** the directory where the script is located?

Comment: Yeah. this example is just for practice. To see how I can return the output of a command in a variable and then do some conditional programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper form for that is

```
myvar=$(pwd)
if [ "$myvar" = /home/vicky ]  ## Need spaces and use `=`.
```

And since you're in bash, you don't need to use `pwd`. Just use `$PWD`. And also, it's preferrable to use `[[ ]]` since variables are not just to word splitting and pathname expansion when in it.

```
myvar=$PWD
if [[ $myvar == /home/vicky ]]
```

Or simply

```
if [[ $PWD == /home/vicky ]]
```